# How to write Short/Int into 1 byte buffer

Tags: arrays, kotlin, bytebuffer

I have these functions:

```
fun asByteArray(value: Short): ByteArray {
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2)
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
    buffer.putShort(value)
    buffer.flip()
    return buffer.array()
}

fun asByteArray(value: Int): ByteArray {
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4)
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
    buffer.putInt(value)
    buffer.flip()
    return buffer.array()
}
```

If the value is 255 then I would like to write it into 1 byte buffer. How can I do it?
If I do `ByteBuffer.allocate(1)` and try to write short/int value then the BufferOverflowException occurs.

Comment: Your actual question has been answered. You should either clarify the question or ask a new question that explains exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write the `Int` directly, write the result of `value.toByte()`:

```
fun asByteArray(value: Short): ByteArray {
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1)
    buffer.put(value.toByte())
    return buffer.array()
}

fun asByteArray(value: Int): ByteArray {
    val buffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1)
    buffer.put(value.toByte())
    return buffer.array()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but if I would like to write Int (4 byte) value "40000" to 2 byte buffer?

Comment: What about writing shorts? (40000 would be an "unsigned short", otherwise you can't have 40000 in a short)

Comment: Yes. It is unsigned short but 40000.toShort() give me -25536. Is it correct buffer.putShort(40000.toShort())?

Comment: The question is: why you need to write 4 bytes in 2? You can write 40000 (which became -25536) and compose it again on destination (supposed that destination knows that you wrote on the first side 2 bytes which are part of 4)

Comment: My idea is that if I have a chance to write number like unsigned then I should do it. 40000 (which became -25536) will be 0x4000 but it is wrong value. 40000 have to be 0x9C40.